# Issue with parenting tracked nulls to get Orientation for mesh

Tags: armature, tracking

I am currently trying to figure out how to get the data that has been tracked from a footage.
I need to track an arm in order to get the movement and replace it with a mesh (that has no hand).
After tracking few points I clicked "Link Empty to Track" and it created nulls moving according to the tracking data. From there I created a bone, added an IK to the first point (Hand track point) to get the orientation and then parent the bone to the Elbow tracking point to get the location. I have also key framed the Z value to have more accuracy.
From here everything is fine, however I tried parenting the mesh to the bone hoping to get the same result, but the mesh just starts to fly around.
I just hope someone can help get a technique where I don't need to match move everything manually.

[image: Illustration of issue]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.
The issue was that I added a Track to constraint to the mesh targetting the hand point therefore creating unpredictable spinning.
Therefore, after removing the constraint from the mesh, I just parent with the mesh to the bone with Automatic Weights, so the mesh will uniquely follow the bone and nothing else.
I keyframed the X Rotation of the bone to match the footage as best as possible.
Hope anyone will find this useful!

[image: Success]